# Epsilon-delta proof of continuity of $1/(x+4)$ at $x = 2$

Tags: limits

Given $f(x) = 1/(x+4),$ how do I show using the definition of limit (i.e., an epsilon-delta proof) that $f$ is continuous at $x = 2$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $f(2) = \dfrac16$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, our goal is to pick a $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ such that for all $x \in \left(2-\delta,2+\delta\right)$, we have $$\left \vert f(x) - \dfrac16 \right \vert < \epsilon, \text{ i.e.,} \left \vert \dfrac1{x+4} - \dfrac16 \right \vert < \epsilon, \text{ i.e.,} \left \vert \dfrac{2-x}{6(4+x)} \right \vert < \epsilon$$
If $\delta < 1$, we have for all $x \in (2-\delta,2+\delta)$, $\dfrac1{4+x} < \dfrac15$. Hence, for $\delta < 1$, if we ensure that $$\left \vert \dfrac{2-x}{6\cdot5} \right \vert < \epsilon$$ we are done. Now for all $x \in (2-\delta,2+\delta)$, we have $\vert 2-x \vert < \delta$. Hence, choose $\delta = \min \left(30 \epsilon,1\right)$.